# Card Flipper Analysis

Tags: algorithm

I'm having an exam in my Data Structures class soon. To prepare I'm looking through some algorithm based problem I've found on the web and run into one that I can't seem to get.

You walk into a room, and see a row of n cards. Each one has a number xi
written on it, where i ranges from 1 to n. However, initially all the cards
are face down. Your goal is to find a local minimum: that is, a card i whose
number is less than or equal to those of its neighbors, xi-1 >=  xi <= xi+1.
The first and last cards can also be local minima, and they only have one
neighbor to compare to. Clearly there can be many local minima, but you
are only responsible for finding one of them.

The only solution I can come up with is basically turning them all over and finding any local minima. However, the challenge is to do this by only turn over O(logn) cards.

Essentially if you see a card "7", it is a local minima if the card on the left is a "10" and the card on the right is "9". How is this done easily in logn time?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If it's in log time, that suggests a binary search type solution when you keep selecting the center card and then divide the remain cards left or right depending on the value.

Comment: It's essentially the same problem as this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238241/find-local-minima-in-an-array

Answer (score 4):

Binary search is the way to go. Here is a rough sketch of how you can do it:

1. Look at the first and last elements. If either is a min, return it.
2. Look at the middle element. If it is a min return it. Otherwise either its left neighbor or right neighbor must be smaller than it. Recurse on that half.

So the idea is that if we know that the left neighbor of the center element is smaller than it, then the left half must have a local min somewhere so we can safely recurse there. The same goes for the right half.

Said differently, the only way that half of the data won't have a local min is if it is either monotonic or goes up and back down, both of which can't happen because we know the endpoint values.

Also the runtime is clearly log(n) because each step takes constant time and we have to do log(n) steps because we cut the data in half each time.