# How can I get this to check all of the elements on one side of the array instead of stopping at one local minimum?

Tags: java, algorithm

When I run this code, it stops at 2 as the local minimum and doesn't check the rest of the values on the other half of the array. It should also print 0 as a local minimum. 
How can I solve this? (it has to be in O(logn) time complexity)

**Code:**

```
public class LocalMinimum {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int[] array = {8, 5, 7, 2, 3, 0, 1, 9};        
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = array.length -1;
    while (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
        int middleIndex = (leftIndex + rightIndex)/2;
        if ((array[middleIndex] < array[middleIndex - 1]) && 
                (array[middleIndex] < (array[middleIndex + 1]))) {
            System.out.println("Local minimum: " + array[middleIndex]);
            break;
        }
        else if (array[middleIndex - 1] < array[middleIndex + 1]) {
            rightIndex = middleIndex - 1;
        }
        else {
            leftIndex = middleIndex + 1;
        }
    }


    }
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the minimum value in an array?

Comment: Can you define specifically what you mean by "local minimum"? Because if it's just any value less than the one before and after it, your fundamental problem is for some reason youve created a Frankenstein like monster by inexplicably combining your local minima search with a binary search. You might want to start over by planning your logic out on paper and then implementing it.

Comment: This is not the right time to use a binary search.  Binary searches are for searching for values in sorted arrays.  Your array isn't sorted--binary search will do you no good.

Comment: sorry, it has to be in O(logn) time complexity, and when I say local minimum, it has to be an integer that is smaller than both the value to the right and left of it. I'm not required to find all the local minimums of the array, so I'm just searching a half of the array

Comment: @NicholasWhitfield Which half are you searching? Searching half of the array would be `O(n/2)` which is `O(n)`, so I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Nicholas Then why do you want it to also output 5 (or 0 since your last edit)? Isn't 2 good enough?

Comment: it should search everything to the right of the value belonging to the middle index, which is 2

Comment: @JasonC And sorting the array would be an `O(nlgn)` operation, even using something like merge or quick sort.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238241/find-local-minima-in-an-array

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
int[] array = {8, 5, 7, 2, 3, 0, 1, 9};

for (int i=0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if ( (i == 0 || array[i] < array[i-1]) &&
         (i == array.length-1 || array[i] < array[i+1])) {
        System.out.println("Local minimum: " + array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a plain old `for` loop:

```
int[] array = {8, 5, 7, 2, 3, 0, 1, 9};

for (int index = 1; index < array.length - 1; index++)
{
    if (array[index] < array[index - 1] &&
        array[index] < array[index + 1])
    {
        System.out.println("Local minimum: " + array[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tim We don't actually know if the OPs definition includes endpoints or not. The way I see it, your answer and this one are two different valid interpretations of an unclear question. Although in the example array it makes no difference.

Comment: that's what I did at first, but it has to be in O(logn) time complexity

Comment: @NicholasWhitfield Please edit your question so that it explains what you're trying to do, and how you want to find that output. That way I can edit my answer so that it matches that question.

Comment: @NicholasWhitfield Are you certain this is your requirement?  How can the search take less than `N` steps to complete, assuming each bucket needs to be examined as a candidate for a local minimum?

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++) {
    if(array[i]<array[i-1] && array[i]<array[i+1]) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```